# Vuex state mutation detected by Vue Dev Tools - component fails to detect change

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

```
mutations: {
    //turns sets values to false/off based on area
    updateGroup(state, { newCodes, areaId}) {
        //area is the codes to change only 
       let area = state.details.find(el => el.id === areaId).markers
       let turnOn = {}
       let turnOff = {}
       for(let i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
           if(newCodes.hasOwnProperty(area[i])) {
               turnOn[area[i]] = area[i]
           } else {
               turnOff[area[i]] = area[i]
           }
       }

       for(let i = 0; i < state.semaforos.length; i++) {
           if(state.semaforos[i].id == turnOn[state.semaforos[i].id]) {
            Vue.set(state.semaforos[i], 'kode', newCodes[state.semaforos[i].id])
           }
           if(state.semaforos[i].id == turnOff[state.semaforos[i].id])
           Vue.set(state.semaforos[i], 'kode', 'off')
       }







    }
}


methods: {
          update(payload) {
          this.$store.commit('updateGroup', payload)
      },
        },
```

> And in component where i call the commit i pull in state

```
computed : {
      ...mapState({
        mapArea(state){
          return state.semaforos
        }
      })
    },
```

> I now manage to get a reactive value from mapState
>   Now the issues is it fails to do so in other components
>
> Thanks in advance for any help that you provide. Have a good day!.
>   Edit: Here are the getters as requested

```
getters: {
    getChange: state => {
        return state.semaforos
    }
},
```

> and state definition Note: I replaced the actual coordinates with ?? for privacy =)

```
state: {
    semaforos: [
         { id : 'V2',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P2',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V3',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},                 
         { id : 'P3',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V4',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P4',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V5',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},        
         { id : 'P5',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V6',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P6',  location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V7',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P7',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V8',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P8',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V9',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P9',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V10',   location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P10',   location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V11',  location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P11',  location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V12',  location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P12',  location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V13',  location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P13',  location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V14',  location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P14',  location: [??], kode : 'off'},
         { id : 'V1',  location: [??], kode : 'off'}, 
         { id : 'P1',  location: [??], kode : 'off'},
    ]
},
```

Comment: can you post ur getters list  ?

Comment: add a state definition please

Comment: ur state does not make sense? it is usually consisted of key value like arrays and single key and value .

Comment: you can have the state inside an array of objs ?

Comment: Its because I need to access the objects based on their ID. Let me see if i can restructure it and make it like this. its what you meant right?
ID03: [ { kode : 'off', location: [??], iD : 'V12', alive: false}, {...}, {...}, {...}]

Comment: what happened to ID01 to ID02?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212659/vuex-state-issue let chat here

Comment: I gotta increase my rep to join apparently.

Comment: The ID01s are for locations the project i was given didnt have those included so maybe they will be adding them in the future.And the order is that way because thats how i gotta show them in a table component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212662/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-yordani-bonilla).

Comment: Listen to your mutation if success replace the edited data from your mutation datalist with the new one. Just create a function to replace object from a list of objects and invoke it on mutation success

Comment: Managed to fix the issue but I tried to watch the mapState change in my component and that didn't work for some reason weird.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related at all with mapState or vuex. Since I am using laravel-echo-server the issue is that I am sending in codes from the linux command line and only have access to that data when listening on a specific channel(I was only listening to that channel on the one component mapState was actually working on...). That was the issue my other component did not have access to that data on that specific channel and so could not receive the updates(or commit the changes with new data thus reflecting the changes on the store). Thanks for all the pointer though guys good day!